# How to correctly evaluate Javascript string containing JSON.parse expression with special characters?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I need to evaluate a JS expression created in the following way

```
function createExprs(obj){
   var decl = "var i = ";
   var value = JSON.stringify(obj);
   var exprs = decl + "JSON.parse('" + value + "')";
   return exprs;
}

var i = createExprs({1:2});//i = "var i = JSON.parse('{"1":4}')"
eval(i); // works fine
```

However it fails when the obj contains any special characters

```
var i = createExprs("today\\.article") \\i="var i = JSON.parse('"today\\.article"')"
eval(i) //  Unexpected token . in JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `"`:

```
"var i = JSON.parse('\"today.article\"')"
```

Comment: Could you specifically point out how inside the function createExprs should I be doing this?